# NodeJS i can't import any module without changing script type to module

Tags: javascript, node.js

My HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <title>TunaChat</title>
</head>
...
</html>
```

My JS

```js
import AOS from "./node_modules/aos"
import "./node_modules/aos/dist/aos.css"
AOS.init()
```

when i run this code it throws a error to console
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`

I tried to add type="module" to my script
`<script src="index.js" type="module"></script>`

Result:
`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/css". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

Also i tried to add type="module" to package.json file

```json
{
  "name": "tunachat",
  "version": "0.2.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Sublimieren-Haupt",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "aos": "^2.3.4"
  }
}
```

Result:
`Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/css". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.`

So Firebase CDN and AOS conflict with each other because i am using type="module"

I am trying to get AOS working.

( I am experiencing the same problem with other packages like firebase NPM )

Comment: dawg bro i ain' finishing this school project

Comment: In what way is your project related to NodeJS? Do you have a webserver like `http` or `express` to serve the HTML? Perhaps you actually want to run your script with NodeJS as opposed to having a document, as NodeJS is purely a JavaScript runtime for a local machine.

Comment: İ use npm module

Comment: Yea that makes no sense. You're trying to load scripts into a web page from some kind of server. Your server is misconfigured; that's what that error about the MIME type means.

Comment: I am running my website from live preview in visual studio code and the MIME error is getting triggered at AOS

Comment: What browser are you using? CSS sheet import only works in Chrome and Edge, not Firefox or Safari.

Comment: i am using Chrome 119.0.6045.200 on Windows 11 22H2